# Cannot get vlc to stream correctly through command line

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, alsa, pulse-audio

I use the following command:

```
vlc -I qt myfile.mp4 #standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst="8080/stream"}  :sout-all :sout-keep
```

and my error log is the following:

```
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055e7143effa0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f61d28bf1d0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f619c004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f619c004960] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f619c004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f619c004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f619c004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f61d27bf470] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  520.61.05   for hardware decoding
```

The main problem seems to be `main decoder error: failed to create audio output`

I have been trying many things for 4 hours (installing various libs, different audio settings in vlc etc) so it is probably a good time to beg for help!

Using Ubuntu 22.04 and GTX970. Have installed CUDA already.

`nmap 192.168.1.x -p 8080` also confirms:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

Many thanks in advance. Just trying to setup a local network streaming with https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-stream-video-from-vlc, it looked really simple at first glance haha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare

```
echo vlc -I qt myfile.mp4 #standard...
```

In many *nix shells unquoted and unescaped `#` begins a comment. Some of the arguments you typed did not get to `vlc` at all! By "installing various libs, different audio settings in vlc etc" you're barking up the wrong tree. The problem occurs before `vlc` even starts.

In this specific case it's best to single-quote the entire `#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst="8080/stream"}` argument, because `{…}` may be expanded by your shell (or may not, depending on the shell). Note this will make the string in single-quotes get to `vlc` literally, including the double-quotes. I guess this is what you want (but I don't know `vlc` enough to really tell).

```
vlc -I qt myfile.mp4 '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst="8080/stream"}'  :sout-all :sout-keep
```

In general, when in doubt, invoke `set -x` before running a command.

> `-x`
> The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set))</sup>

This way you will see what command(s) you're really executing. Note [`set -x` will add some quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343027/108618) to what it prints, so in general you need to know how to interpret them. Still in a case like yours, where some "arguments" are discarded as a comment, the output of `set -x` will show you the issue clearly. Turn the feature off by `set +x`.

If the fixed command doesn't do what you want, *then* it's time to blame `vlc`, audio settings and such.

Meta note: if it still doesn't work and `set -x` tells you the command is exactly as you expected, and you need further help, then it may be good to ask a separate question instead of [going chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310). An actual issue (if any) with `vlc` will be unrelated to the issue with the command line we've just solved.

Comment: It's indeed working much better you were right regarding the comment, thank you a lot! but the port 8080 is still closed. And I still cannot access the stream, using `vlc -I qt a.mp4 '#http{mux=ts{mux=mp4},dst=8080/stream}' --sout-all --sout-keep`

Comment: follow-up: https://superuser.com/questions/1753674/streaming-with-vlc-but-port-8080-is-still-closed