# Streaming local file through http with VLC

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, localhost, video-streaming

[original question for reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1753609/cannot-get-vlc-to-stream-correctly-through-command-line/)

using `vlc -I qt a.mp4 '#http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=mp4},dst=:8080/stream}' --sout-all --sout-keep` the video is playing locally fine with both audio and video but I got some error messages:

```
[00007f01f0004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f01f0004960] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f01f0004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f01f0004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f01f0004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f022584cdd0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  520.61.05  Thu Sep 29 05:28:13 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[hevc @ 0x7f0225860680] Failed setup for format vdpau: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
[00007f022584cdd0] avcodec decoder error: existing hardware acceleration cannot be reused
[00007f01f0004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f01f0004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
```

The file is not looking like it is being streamed as `nmap 192.168.1.x -p 8080` also confirms:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

Using Ubuntu 22.04 and GTX970. Have installed CUDA already.

On the client side if I enter `http://192.168.1.x:8080/stream` I get "multiple media cannot be played" error.

---

edit following Tonny recommandation I installed drivers update `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

But still get:

```
[00007f5ef8004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f5ef8004960] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f5ef8004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f5ef8004960] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f5ef8004960] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f5f24ce6000] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  515.65.01  Wed Jul 20 13:42:26 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
```

---

edit2: after switching from `automatic` to `VDPAU video decoder` in VLC Input Codec settings -> Hardware-accelerated decoding all the error messages are gone but still the original problem remains

---

edit 3: Once the file stop playing I get the following error:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/my/path/%23http%7Bmux%3Dffmpeg%7Bmux%3Dmp4%7D%2Cdst%3D%3A8080/stream%7D'.
```

Comment: Maybe thete is a firewall in place? Does **iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT** fix the issue - at least temporarily?

Comment: A bunch of those errors have nothing to do with streaming, but with the nvidia driver. The actual driver, NOT the CUDA stuff.

Comment: @davidgo there is currently no firewall. I ran the command (just in case) but still not fixing anything.

Comment: Try in VLC to disable "Hardware accelerated decoding", to avoid using the NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: @harrymc after updating the drivers the hardware decoding acceleration seems to be working fine, at least there is no error message!

Comment: So the problem has disappeared?

Comment: it did not, still unable to access the stream and port 8080 remains closed

Comment: Check with `netstat -tulpn` on your machine running vlc to make sure that this is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all thanks to everyone for the help. Each milestone got me closer to the goal!

I figured out that the main problem was coming from the video itself, it had to be made streamable first of all for http streaming ([Creating MP4 videos ready for HTTP streaming](https://superuser.com/questions/438390/creating-mp4-videos-ready-for-http-streaming))!

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -movflags faststart b.mp4
```

Then the command that got it working was:

```
vlc -I qt b.mp4 :sout="#http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080}" :sout-all :sout-keep
```

in the client:

```
http://192.168.1.x:8080
```

Still have a little problem where the video is black in the first 3 seconds while I'm already getting the audio, need to figure out the caching part!